# file redirect issue with command ECHO

Tags: windows, cmd

I've had a problem in the past, trying to do this :

```
echo 2> test.txt
```

To be clear, I would like to put text "2" into file `test.txt`
Now, I know you can solve this issue doing this:

```
echo.2> test.txt
```

But, the problem moves a little bit, when I try to do this:

```
echo sometext 2> test.txt
```

To be clear again, I would like to echo text "sometext 2" into a file. So, trying the same trick:

```
echo.sometext 2> test.txt
```

... but it doesn't work, as it seems that the dot has no effect on what is put after the first whitespace. (What he does instead, is just echoing `sometext`, and putting error messages into test.txt. But, there are no error messages, but he does create a file, be it an empty one.)

The issue expands to other values, like

```
echo sometext 8> test.txt
```

which does exactly the same as when you replace 8 with 2. And when you do this :

```
echo sometext 1> test.txt
```

he will create file "test.txt" only with content "sometext".

Question : how do I get this command to work:

```
echo sometext 2> test.txt
```

But, the question must be asked in context of the fact that "sometext 2" is a string on itself, can be represented by a variable like `%some_variable%` and it is very hard to manipulate anything inside that string. To be more clear:

I know this works:

```
echo sometext ^2> test.txt
```

But, that means I have to change the text "sometext 2" to "sometext ^2". Which is not impossible, but it would be easier if I could manipulate the command around it.

Is that possible, how ?

ps: I know also this works:

```
echo "sometext 2"> test.txt
```

But then the quotes are included in the output file. Same with single quotes. And I don't want the quotes to be inside the outputfile.

Comment: I am not quite sure about how window's cmd works, but in unix `some-command 2>file` will redirect `some-command`'s STDERR to the file. Since your echo command does not write to STDERR, you dont see anything in the file. Try: `echo hello 2 > file` (notice the space between `2` and `>`

Comment: The space is indeed another trick, but then it creates a trailing space into the file itself ... and I don't want that, because the value in the file must be the text (in this case "hello 2") and nothing else, also no trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character directly beore the redirector may not be anumeric.

Put the redirector at the start of the line.

```
>test.txt echo 2
```

A redirector after a numeric redirects that device; `2` being stderr, `1` being stdout, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in parentheses:

```
(echo sometext 2)> file.txt
(echo %some_variable%)> file.txt
```